# My app is changing the way it looks

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm pretty new to objective-c and I am working on my first app, I changed the design a little bit on it to make it look more nice and it was working fine, but then it started crashing every time i pushed a button. And now when i run it it looks like the way i had designed it before. but it still looks normal in my storyboard. This has happened to me before so i just made a new project and copy and pasted the old files and storyboard into the new one and it worked fine until now. Can anyone help me?

Comment: a) Try running 'clean' b) Try 'rm -fr ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData'

Comment: I tried cleaning it but it didnt work. And what do i do when i get to derivedData

Comment: You can remove the DerivedData directory. . . It's like a sure-fire squeaky clean. . It looks like you've got stale resources turning up in your app.

Comment: ok so just remove all the files in it

Comment: I did that and now im getting a sigabrt error

Comment: Update the question with the error. Using xibs? Perhaps something not wired up in a xib.

Comment: there is no more sigabrt error anymore but it still looks like the old design and in the debug area it says. 2013-10-14 14:27:33.642 HomeworkList[14648:a0b] WARNING: Slow defaults access for key Internal took 0.029127 seconds, tolerance is 0.020000